# Result is declared but its value is never read on ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a following code

```
async register(user: User){
try {
  const result = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
  this.userRegister();
}
catch {
  this.showAlert();
}
```

}

But when I run the command `ionic build --release --prod` the terminal tells me the following message

```
  tslint: C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/GuiaCorretor/src/pages/register/register.ts, line: 39
      'result' is declared but its value is never read.

    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      this.userRegister();
```

Comment: I think it's complaining that you aren't doing anything with your `result` variable. Try just doing `await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);` instead. Sounds like a linter error rather than a compiler error

Comment: Thank you! Please put your answer as a question so that I can mark the matter as resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's complaining that you aren't doing anything with your result variable. Try just doing
`await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);` instead. Sounds like a linter error rather than a compiler error

To disable the rule (coming from `tslint`) you can update it:

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/